# How to get number of selected item from a ComboBox in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

How to get the number of the selected item in ComboBox?
For example:

- (0) item 1
- (1) item 2
- (2) [item 3]     *// imagine this option is selected*
- (3) item 4

How I can get value 2?

Comment: javadoc is your friend ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SingleSelectionModel selectionModel = comboBox.getSelectionModel();
int index = selectionModel.getSelectedIndex();
```

check below API documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedIndex--

Comment: Looks like a perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

`comboBox.getItems().indexOf(comboBox.getValue())`

This worked for me

Comment: yeah, that's also possible - curious why you are choosing the detour?

Comment: @kleopatra I had no idea about ```getSelectionModel()``` method and found my own solution and tested it and it worked. However, this option might have some issues with the same objects in the list when ```getSelectionModel()``` is exactly what I need so I tried it instead.

Comment: thanks :) yeah, duplicates in the list are not well supported (in the selection), you might run into known issues (don't have a reference handy right now, sry)